# Open source wrapper library for all major brokers for submitting orders and getting prices?

Tags: wrapper, fix-protocol, algorithmic-trading

Is there a single open source library which contains API calls for each brokers to do common functionalities like, get price ticks, submit orders?

for ex)

```
buy("MSFT",33); //will send buy order to Interactive Brokers, MBtrade etc.
```

Basically I am looking to run some algorithm trades to multiple brokers.

Is there an existing solution out there?

paid ones would be okay too.

preferably Java or cross-platform support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Algo-Trader](http://code.google.com/p/algo-trader/wiki/AlgoTraderDocumentation) and [Tradelink](http://code.google.com/p/tradelink/) are a couple of platforms that provide the capability to connect to multiple brokers and data providers using a single programming interface.

If you want to check out a paid option you can check out [Openquant](http://www.smartquant.com/) or [RightEdge](http://www.rightedgesystems.com/) - both provide a month's free trial.

There are quite a few trading platforms out there but only you'll be in a position to decide which one best fits your needs.

Answer (score 2):

[Quickfixj](http://www.quickfixj.org/) is an open source FIX engine for Java

[Cameron](http://www.camerontec.com/)  is a commercially available.

I have worked on both of them so I can recommend them but you have to evaluate each one for your needs before you decide on one.
There are multiples of them available, just google for a FIX engine.

Answer (score 2):

Also there is [Tradelink](http://code.google.com/p/tradelink/) and [CEP Trader](http://code.google.com/p/cep-trader/)